# Oracle ORA-01427: single row subquery returns more than one rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to parse the CSV file and store data in table. How I can do this. File is stored in table in blob type. This is first problem. Second, Oracle Apex "said" what code bellow don't work because subquery returned more than one row. But I don't see this place when he returning more then one row. If exist different way to store data from file in table you can suggest it. Thanks a lot.

```
DECLARE
    l_ln      NUMBER;
    l_col1    VARCHAR2(255);
    l_col2    VARCHAR2(255);
    l_col3    VARCHAR2(255);
    l_col4    VARCHAR2(255);
    l_col5    NUMBER;
    l_col6    DATE;
    l_col7    DATE;
    l_col8    NUMBER;
    l_col9    NUMBER;
    l_col10   VARCHAR2(255);
    l_min_ln  NUMBER;
    l_max_ln  NUMBER;
BEGIN

/* start and stop  */ 
SELECT
        MIN(line_number),
        MAX(line_number)
    INTO
        l_min_ln,
        l_max_ln
    FROM
        t_files                                                                                          f,
        TABLE ( apex_data_parser.parse(p_content => f.f_blob, p_file_name => f.f_name) )              p
    WHERE
            f.file_id = :p5_file
        AND line_number > 1;
/* end */
    FOR counter IN l_min_ln..l_max_ln LOOP
        SELECT
            ff,
            mm
            ll,
            bd,
            (
                SELECT
                    id
                FROM
                    country
                WHERE
                    upper(name) LIKE upper('%'
                                               || :country
                                               || '%')
            ) co,
            dtn,
            ind,
            no,
            np
        INTO
            l_col1,
            l_col3,
            l_col2,
            l_col4,
            l_col5,
            l_col6,
            l_col7,
            l_col8,
            l_col9
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    line_number  id_l,
                    col001       ff,
                    col002       mm,
                    col003       ll
                    col004       bd,
                    col005       co,
                    col006       dtn,
                    col007       ind,
                    col008       no,
                    col009       np,
                    col010       col
                FROM
                    temp_files                            f,
                    TABLE ( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                                    p_content => f.f_blob, 
                                                    p_skip_rows => counter - 1,
                                                    p_max_rows => counter,
                                                    p_file_name => f.f_name
                                                  ) ) p
                WHERE
                        f.file_id = :p5_file
                    AND line_number = counter
            ) temp_table
        WHERE
            id_l = counter;

        IF l_col1 IS NOT NULL OR l_col2 IS NOT NULL OR l_col3 IS NOT NULL OR l_col4 IS NOT NULL OR l_col5 IS NOT NULL OR l_col6 IS
        NOT NULL OR l_col7 IS NOT NULL OR l_col8 IS NOT NULL OR l_col9 IS NOT NULL OR l_col10 IS NOT NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO tbn (
                d1,
                d2,
                d3,
                d4,
                d5,
                d6,
                d7,
                d8,
                d9
            ) VALUES (
                l_col1,
                l_col2,
                l_col3,
                to_date(l_col4),
                l_col5,
                to_date(l_col6),
                to_date(l_col7),
                l_col8 || l_col9,
                to_date(sysdate)
            );

            COMMIT;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Do a JOIN instead.

Comment: I would suspect the inline subquery for country id: `WHERE upper(name) LIKE upper('%'|| :country|| '%')` does not look like it will always give 1 unique result. Is :country empty in some of the cases?

Comment: Use in the subquery instead `select max(id) || case when count(*) > 1 then 'DUPLICATED! '|| count(*) end ...` this returns one row only and you can see which ID is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this in 1 statement:

```
INSERT INTO tbn ( d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9 ) 
    select col001, col002, col003, to_date(col004), c.id, 
           to_date(col006), to_date(col007), col008||col009, sysdate
    from TEMP_FILES f,
         TABLE ( apex_data_parser.parse( p_content => f.f_blob, 
                                         p_file_name => f.f_name ) ) p,
         COUNTRY c
    WHERE  f.file_id = :p5_file
      and upper(c.name) LIKE upper('%' || col005 || '%')
      and ( col001 is not null or col002 is not null or 
            col003 is not null or col004 is not null or
            col005 is not null or col006 is not null or 
            col007 is not null or col008 is not null or
            col009 is not null or col010 is not null);
```